# How to access MS Access queries (not normal tables) using Java?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am having trouble getting data from a query in MS Access using UcanAcess library in java.

In Access you can create normal tables - getting data from there is no problem.
You can also create a "query", that means you create a table by using informations from different tables.

Still, when using the same code and just changing the name of the table, I get following error, which means he can not find it or I am not allowed to access (it is probably about not finding it):

UCAExc:::4.0.4 user lacks privilege or object not found: ALLE OE RG ABFRAGE

Here is the method I am using:

```
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/B070252/Desktop/KopieAuswertungen.accdb"); //AuswertungenZBAV
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [ALLE OE RG ABFRAGE]");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
    return null;
```

Note: I am using UcanAccess, but the trouble is not with the library. I am thankful for every tip or solution and hope you can help me.

Comment: The exception is very clear. You should match the name of the table you are trying to access character by character to see if there is a mismatch. Also, check the privileges. There are roles in Access which you will need to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This file belongs to me and the characters are 100% the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: Causes and solutions I've read: 1) db damage corrected by running Compact & Repair in Access; 2) Access query (or any query it is dependent on) has dynamic parameter, if so, remove it.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic parameters"? I am trying to select * from a table

Comment: I don't think UCanAccess supports querying off other queries. If it did, it'd be partly useable at best, Access supports stuff in queries like querying random ODBC databases, calling VBA functions, etc. that would be near impossible to implement.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't think about that but it makes sense. I will just create a copy as a table then.

Comment: @Anton - Is [ALLE OE RG ABFRAGE] a SELECT query that *only* refers to other tables in the Access database, or does it refer to external resources like ODBC linked tables or pass-through queries?

Comment: No it doesnt, it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, I copied the data from the query and pasted it in a normal table. I can read the normal table now